Range of parameter $a$ and an inequality related to zeros of $f(x) = ax^2 - x - \ln x$

Suppose $ f(x) = ax^2 - x - \ln x$ (with a parameter $a\in \mathbb{R}$) has two distinct positive real zero points $x_{1}$ and $x_{2}$,
i.e. $f(x_{1}) = 0$ and $f(x_{2}) = 0$.
$(1)$ Calculate the range of $a$
$(2)$ Prove that: $$(2x_{1} + \ln x_{2})(2x_{2} + \ln x_{1}) > 4.$$

Background:
I am dealing with questions about derivatives and inequality.
Attemps:
(1)I found out that the range of a should be $(0, 1)$
(2)I do not have any clue how to prove that. It is hard for me to deal with $x_{2}\dot lnx_{2}$ or $lnx_{1}\dot lnx_{2}$
My detail attempts:
(1) $f(x) = 0$, $ax^2-x-lnx=0$ $(x>0)$
$$a=\frac{lnx+x}{x^2}$$
Let $$g(x)=\frac{lnx+x}{x^2}$$
$$g‘(x)=\frac{1-x-2lnx}{x^3}$$
Let $$u(x)=1-x-2lnx$$
$$u'(x)=-1-\frac{2}{x}<0$$
$u(x)$ is decreasing function at $x>0$
$$u(1) = 0$$
$$g(x)max = g(1)=1$$
$$g(\frac{1}{e})=\frac{-1+\frac{1}{e}}{\frac{1}{e}^2}<0$$
$$g(x)>0 x>1$$
$$lim\frac{lnx+x}{x^2}=lim\frac{\frac{1}{x}+1}{2x}=lim\frac{x+1}{2x^2}=\frac{1}{4x}=0$$
So
$$0<a<1$$
(2)$$\frac{1}{e}<x_{1}<1<x_{2}$$

What have you tried till now? Provide some working so we can help you with where you are stuck.

@Dstarred i added my working, please check it.

You will find Bolzano's theorem helpful for part 1

@qucchia though I work the part 1 out, but could you provide a url which include detailed explanation about "Bolzano's theorem"? Thanks ahead.

Sure, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem for example

@qucchia I see I am exactly using the Bolzano's theorem though I did not realize it, thanks.

I'll try to solve it, but for some reason, the question has been closed? Why so?

@Gwen Because the author did not provide context, attempts, etc when he posted the question. Did you have a simple solution? I also have a solution, but it is quite complicated.

@RiverLi I can't seem to get $\ln x_1 \ln x_2$ in the expression without multiplying $f(x_1)$ and $f(x_2)$

@Gwen Does your approach via integral work?

I am trying to reopen the question

@Gwen@RiverLi could you help reopen it or fasten the process to reopen the question?

@RiverLi it's giving a lot of data, but I've got a physics exam tomorrow, for which I need to study atleast an entire book. I'm terribly sorry, and after returning from school I'll definitely contribute something to this question :")

@Gwen Fine. Take your time. I just saw you said "I'll try to solve it, but for some reason, the question has been closed? Why so? " And then asked you if you have a simple solution.

$$
Let \ \ g(x) = \frac{x + ln(x)}{x^2} \\
f(x_1)=f(x_2) \Rightarrow g(x_1)=g(x_2)
\Rightarrow 
\frac{x_1+ln(x_1)}{x_1^2} = \frac{x_2+ln(x_2)}{x_2^2} \\
\\
Check \ [\ ln(x) \sim \frac{1}{2}(x-\frac{1}{x}) \ ] \Rightarrow 
\left\{\begin{matrix}
ln(x) > \frac{1}{2}(x-\frac{1}{x}) \ \ \ \ 0 < x < 1 \\
ln(x) < \frac{1}{2}(x-\frac{1}{x}) \ \ \ \ x > 1
\end{matrix}\right. \\
Calculate \ \ [ \ g(\frac{1}{x_1})-g(x_1) \ ] = x_1-x_1^2 \cdot ln(x_1)-\frac{x_1+ln(x_1)}{x_1^2} \\
= x_1-\frac{1}{x_1}-ln(x_1) \cdot (x_1^2\ + \frac{1}{x_1^2}) \\
> x_1- \frac{1}{x_1} - \frac{1}{2}(x_1-\frac{1}{x_1}) \cdot 2 = 0 \\
So \ \ g(\frac{1}{x_1})>g(x_1)=g(x_2), \ The \ g(x) \ is \ monotonically \ decreasing \ on \ the \ interval \ (1,∞), \ and \ \frac{1}{x_1} > 1, x_2 > 1. \\
So \ we \ get \ [ \ x_1x_2 > 1 \ ]. \\
\\
So \ \ (2x_1 + ln(x_2)) \cdot (2x_2 + ln(x_1))>(2x_1-ln(x_1)) \cdot (\frac{2}{x_1}+ln(x_1)) \\
=4+2x_1 \cdot ln(x_1)-\frac{2}{x_1} \cdot ln(x_1)-ln^2(x_1) \\
Just \ need \ to \ prove \ \ [ \ 2x_1 \cdot ln(x_1)-\frac{2}{x_1} \cdot ln(x_1)-ln^2(x_1) > 0 \ ] \\
\Rightarrow 
2x_1-\frac{2}{x_1}-ln(x_1) < 0 \\
By \ using \ [ \ 2 \cdot (x_1 - \frac{1}{x_1})<\frac{1}{2} \cdot (x_1 - \frac{1}{x_1}) < ln(x_1) \ ]
\ \ It's \ correct.
$$

@River Li You're right, it's actually > not <, I've revised my answer.

It is very nice!
